# an import error: cannot import name 'getargspec_no_self' from 'scipy._lib._util'

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

When using scipy's `optimize`, I encountered an error such as `cannot import name 'getargspec_no_self' from 'scipy._lib._util'`. My computer runs windows rather than ubuntu, so I can't understand the answer from the previous question. Here are my codes in two situations. They all ended up in the same result.

situation1:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
def f(x):
    return x**2 + 10 * np.sin(x)
x_data = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.1)
plt.plot(x_data, f(x_data))
plt.show()
result = optimize.minimize(x, x0=0)
print(result)
```

situation2:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
x_data = np.linspace(-5, 5, num=50)
y_data = 2.9 * np.sin(1.5 * x_data) + np.random.normal(size=50)
def test_func(x, a, b):
    return a * sin(b * x)
params, params_covariance = optimize.curve_fit(test_func, x_data, y_data, p0=[2,2])
print(params)
```

When I use other submodules from Scipy, there is nothing wrong. Hence, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Your first example uses `optimize.minimize(x, x0=0)`, but `x` is nowhere defined. You probably want to use `f`.  Can you check whether you have the latest scipy and numpy versions installed?

Comment: yes, it should be x_data. but I made some mistakes when pasted it. I'm sure that I have the latest versions because yesterday I upgraded all of them.

Comment: It really doesn't work with `optimize.minimize(xdata, x0=0)`. You need `optimize.minimize(f, x0=0)`. Please edit your question and make the necessary adjustments. Also, please double check that you are running the latest versions. `print(scipy.__version__)` should show something like '1.5.2'